# Networking bits to number of subnets

Tags: networking, subnet, ip-address, network-design

How does one use the value of networking bits of a class A address to find the number of subnet bits and host bits? For example, with a subnet mask of /22, what would be the process of finding the host bits and subnet bits?

*I know a class C address would be networking bits - 24 = subnet bits and 8-subnet bits = host bits. This method doesn't work directly for class A addresses.

Comment: CIDR is a thing for a LOOONG time now.